# How to get Data from Database with ASP.NET without Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and I've been trying to get data from the database to show up on my dynamic web page so that `[first_name], [weight_data] and [date]` are taken from a database.

I've been looking through documentation and all I see are Gridview tutorials, how do I take the value of `SELECT [first_name] FROM [userData] WHERE id='1` from the database showing just the `first_name` string and nothing else?

Thank you.

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web_Portal_Final.About" %>

    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
        <h3>This is where your data goes</h3>
        <p>Once the app can record data, this will be set.</p>
        <p>Hi, [first_name] Your weight is [weight_data]. This was taken on [date].</p>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"><Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [first_name] FROM [userData] WHERE id='1'" ID="SqlDataSource2"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: this is actually quite simple do a quick google search.. search for the `Fill()` method there are plenty was to get data from a database `SqlDataReader` is another..

Comment: less than 1 second a simple google search yields `646,000` results on `C# WebForms get data from database using DataReader` here is one SO link you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696371/how-to-retrieve-and-display-data-from-sql-to-aspx-webform

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I can already get the data from a database. But I just don't know how to take it out from the gridview and make it a string instead. It shows up as a string inside column boxes.